# The Missing Handlebar

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

I've been trying to look for the handlebar piece but it doesn't show up. Can someone tell me why?[image]

Comment: Where are you looking? I'm pretty sure it would show up if I looked in the right pile.

Comment: @Henrik unless the vacuum cleaner got it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where are you looking, but it is readily available on BrickLink in seven colors: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30031&idColor=85#T=C&C=85

Answer (score 2):

Welcome *User11225*!

In your *LEGO* program or webpage type in the part number instead, which would be, "30031".

Why: Search words vary across media, and it's harder to misspell or *mis-describe* numbers.

Example:

- On *Bricklink.com* the description includes the "**s**" to spell
  handlebar**s**.
- In *LEGO Digital Draw* the description just calls this piece a "handle"
  and drops the "bars".

Search fields can get finicky.